# Query on opacity - HTML, CSS & Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I had set the `opacity` of the bootstrap card to 0.8. I want the table to be opaque and other part of the card to be translucent. How to achieve this? I tried to add style `opacity : 1` to the table and it isn't working.

[image]

Comment: on the card itself you should just change the background color to an RGBA equivalent, so something like `background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);` and remove the opacity statement.

Comment: In cases like this, you should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to make the contents of translucent parent to be fully opaque. Instead, in your case, you can make the background of the parent to be translucent and keep the opacity fine:

```css
body {background: url("https://i.imgur.com/vifaloim.jpg"); margin: 25px;}
.parent {background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75); margin: 10px; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;}
.child {margin: 10px; background: #fff; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; min-height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```